# 403 error when requesting POST or PUT during Spring RestAPI development

Tags: spring, spring-security, cors, http-status-code-403

I am trying to implement and use Rest API in a project to which Spring 5 + Spring Security 5 is applied.

When testing with Postman after running Tomcat locally

`url: http://localhost:8080/api~`

It has been confirmed that requests such as get, post, and put work normally.

I uploaded this project to https server and while testing the api on the server in local Postman,

A 403 forbidden error occurred in requests such as put and post, excluding get requests.

When I googled, it said that Spring Security's csrf problem + cors handling problem.

---

So I changed the code like that.

- WebSecurityConfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()                   
                   ~
                   .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                 ~                  
                .and()
                    .logout()
               ~
                .and()
                    .httpBasic().disable().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    ~
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return source;
    }
```

- WebMvcConfig

```
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
```

- Controller

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
```

But in freflight request it returns 200 normally, but in this request I still get 403.

Which part is wrong? I would appreciate it if you let me know :)

Comment: Hi mandy, welcome to StackOverflow. This is not really an answer. Please edit your original question if you want to add more info or provide a different example

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration add add Cors filter via the HttpSecurity builder.
i.e.

```
Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .........
```

This will enable cors preflight requests which are used by PUT and POST.
you should not need to include a CorsConfigurationSource, just make sure you have the @CrossOrigin annotation in your Controllers as well.